# Why are pthread mutex and condvar sizes are so large?

Tags: pthreads

I just noticed that pthread_mutex_t and cond_t are quite large.   This is on a X86_64 machine using gcc.

```
     size(pthread_mutex_t)=40   sizeof(pthread_cond_t)=48
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: 40 and 48 characters really don't seem "that large".. in any case [see the definition source](http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_3.1.1/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/libpthread-ddefs.html) (or one variation of it) for what sorts of goodies they might contain. Other than some padding in pthread_cond_t, everything looks like it serves a purpose - diving into the actual implementation source should show *how* such are used.

Comment: Thats fair.  Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: @user2864740 They seem quite large considering that they are 10 and 12 times larger than on 32-bit platform.